# Reserve internet connection

Tags: windows-xp, internet, home-networking

I have the router D-link 804HV that have 20mbit\s internet via PPoE tunnel . It connect three PC with Windows Xp to my home net. One of three my PC have reserve stability wi-fi internet connection. How can I use the wi-fi connection as reserve if the router connection is not available?
I try to set the Wi-fi PC as gate for the other two, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to accomplish.

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Select Network Connections
3. Click Advanced
4. Just make sure your PPoe Connection is listed higher than the WiFi connection

Step 4 defines the priority of network connections.

Comment: Will internet be work at others PC in my home net?